# Edit PHP/AJAX to deal with DELETE OR EDIT

Tags: php, ajax

First of all before i show you the code i will explain how my webpage works.

1. User selects date -> AJAX Calls On Date Change
2. Resulting PHP data displays in two sections on page.
3. First Section is Orders Table Contents
4. Second Section is Items Table Contents (not including the items inside Orders)

What i am trying to add is functionality to 3 buttons that will change the tables dynamically using AJAX. 
I currently have working non ajax requests.

Here is the Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.date-picker').change(function(){
            $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'php/getproduct.php',
                 data: {dateorderpicker: $('.date-picker').val()},
                 dataType: 'JSON',
                 success: function(data)
                 {
                    $("#cartrow").html(data.result_1);
                    $("#otheritems").html(data.result_2);
                 }
             });
         });
     });
```

PHP file for Current AJAX:

```
session_start();
    include('db_config.php');
    $datepicker = $_POST['dateorderpicker'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE deliveryDate = ? AND customerId = ? "; 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $datepicker, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $_SESSION['customer_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    $container = array();
    $data['result_1'] = $data['result_2'] = '';
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $container[] = "'{$row['itemName']}'"; // put them inside a temporary container
        $data['result_1'] .= '
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="content-boxes style-two top-column clearfix animated flipInY" style="opacity: 1;">
                    <div class="content-boxes-text">
                        <form action="php/edit.php" method="post" class="form-inline pull-right">    
                            <h3>' . $row['itemName'] . '</h3>
                            <h4>Total Price: $'.$row['price'].'</h4>    
                            <img src="../wholesale/img/sourdough.jpg" class="img-reponsive">
                            <p>Our best seller.  Full of flavour.</p>
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Qty</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="number" name="qty" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" value="' . $row['qty'] . '">
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'">
                            <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                            <button type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-primary">Remove</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- //.content-boxes-text -->
                </div>
                <!-- //.content-boxes -->
            </div>
        ';
    }

    if(!empty($container)){

        $excluded_names = implode(',', $container);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE itemName NOT IN($excluded_names)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $price ="";
            if ($_SESSION['customer_band'] == 'A') {
               $price = $row['bandA'];
            }
            else if ($_SESSION['customer_band'] == 'B') {
                $price = $row['bandB'];
            } 
            else if ($_SESSION['customer_band'] == 'C') {
                $price = $row['bandC'];
            }
            else if ($_SESSION['customer_band'] == 'D') {
                $price = $row['bandD'];
            }
            else if ($_SESSION['customer_band'] == 'E') {
                $price = $row['bandE'];
            }

            $data['result_2'] .= '
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="content-boxes style-two top-column clearfix animated flipInY" style="opacity: 1;">
                    <div class="content-boxes-text">
                        <form action="php/additem.php" method="post" class="form-inline pull-right">
                            <h4>'.$row['itemName'].'</h4><input id="itemname" type="hidden" name="itemName" value="'.$row['itemName'].'">
                            <h3>$'.$price.'</h3><input id="price" type="hidden" name="pricetotal" value="'.$price.'">
                            <img src="../wholesale/img/sourdough.jpg" class="img-reponsive">
                            <p>'.$row['description'].'</p><input id="description" type="hidden" name="description" value="'.$row['description'].'">
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Qty</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                            <input id="qty" type="number" name="qty" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="How Many?">
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" id="additem" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- //.content-boxes-text -->
                </div>
                <!-- //.content-boxes -->
            </div>
        ';
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM item";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $price ="";
            if ($_SESSION['customer_band'] == 'A') {
               $price = $row['bandA'];
            }
            else if ($_SESSION['customer_band'] == 'B') {
                $price = $row['bandB'];
            } 
            else if ($_SESSION['customer_band'] == 'C') {
                $price = $row['bandC'];
            }
            else if ($_SESSION['customer_band'] == 'D') {
                $price = $row['bandD'];
            }
            else if ($_SESSION['customer_band'] == 'E') {
                $price = $row['bandE'];
            }

            $data['result_2'] .= '
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="content-boxes style-two top-column clearfix animated flipInY" style="opacity: 1;">
                        <div class="content-boxes-text">
                            <form action="php/additem.php" method="post" class="form-inline pull-right">
                                <h4>'.$row['itemName'].'</h4><input type="hidden" name="itemName" value="'.$row['itemName'].'">
                                <h3>$'.$price.'</h3><input type="hidden" name="pricetotal" value="'.$price.'">   
                                <img src="../wholesale/img/sourdough.jpg" class="img-reponsive">
                                <p>'.$row['description'].'</p><input type="hidden" name="description" value="'.$row['description'].'">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Qty</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="number" name="qty" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="How Many?">
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" id="additem" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <!-- //.content-boxes-text -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- //.content-boxes -->
                </div>
            ';
            }
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
```

Both Update and Delete PHP file:

```
include('db_config.php');

if (isset($_POST['update']))
{
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

echo $id;

$sql = "UPDATE orders SET qty=? WHERE id=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($qty,$id));

header('Location: ../order.php');
}
if (isset($_POST['delete']))
{
$id = $_POST['id'];

$sql = "DELETE FROM orders WHERE id=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($id));

header('Location: ../order.php');
}
```

The code above needs to be converted to AJAX, and both sections on the page using ajax should update the table automatically. It might be that you will call the first ajax query to reload the tables correctly?

Thanks for having a look at this. 
I am having trouble wrapping my head around how i should get this work.

Alex

Comment: What do you mean that "the code above needs to be converted into Ajax"? You mean you want to convert it into Javascript or you want to do some kind of asyncronous operation in php?

Comment: Oh right, well i am trying to make it so when i click delete, the delete php will be called and then the sections on the page updated to display the change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy you can give a class (NOTE : yes class  ) to your update button and similarly to delete button

Suppose your update button has class "update_task"

but your content was added to DOM after DOM already loaded, so you will need to create two ajax request with DELEGATE Methods for delete and update.

For delegate reference  - 
http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

// for update

```
 $("body").delegate(".update_task","click",function(){
   current_id = $(this).previous("input:hidden").val() // for current update button id,
       $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'php/update_product.php',
             data: {id: current_id, othervalues: other_value_of_choice},
             dataType: 'JSON',
             success: function(data)
             {
                if(data==1)
               {
                   // what ever you want to do if data has been updated
               }
             }
         });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Send AJAX request to PHP for update/delete. Return result of operation (true/false).
2. If result is true, update/remove from html with javascript(jquery).

By the way, don't use redirect, when you call php via ajax.